# Process has exited, so the requested information is not available

Tags: c#, process

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
  
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    { try
        {
            Print();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\fold1\Log.txt", ex.ToString());
        }
        
    }
    public static void Print()
    {
        //Print & Move the files after printing
        DirectoryInfo sourceinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\fold");
        DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\fold1");

        foreach (FileInfo fi in sourceinfo.GetFiles())
        {
            if (fi.Length != 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                process.Refresh();

                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
                process.StartInfo.FileName = fi.FullName;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                process.Start();

                process.WaitForInputIdle();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(18000);
                if (!process.CloseMainWindow())
                    process.Kill();

                MoveFile(fi.FullName);
               

            }
        }
    }

    public static void MoveFile(string Filename)
    {
        string SourcePath = @"C:\fold";
        string targetpath = @"C:\fold1";


        if (!Directory.Exists(targetpath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetpath);
        }

        string[] sourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath);

        foreach (string sourcefile in sourceFiles)
        {
            string mfilename = Path.GetFullPath(sourcefile);
            string mname = Path.GetFileName(sourcefile);

            if (mfilename == Filename)
            {
                string distnition = Path.Combine(targetpath, mname);
                File.Move(mfilename, distnition);
            }
        }

    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\fold1\stop.txt", "Stop method");

    }
}
```

I created a windows service that prints all the pdf(which means i need to use adobe reader or some other pdf reader) files in a directory  but when I run it , it does nothing , I wrote my code so that any error is edited into a file and this is what it gives me "Process has exited, so the requested information is not available".

Comment: Are all of your files associated with an application, as that will be what's required to print them?

Comment: Could you be killing the process early? Try increasing the wait time to more than 18 seconds.

Comment: Yes , sorry I forgot to mention it , all my files are pdf so I need to associate them with a pdf reader to print them

Comment: I used all of suggestions but now the service won't even start , I get this error " error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to close the process after it has exited with `Process.CloseMainWindow` ([see the docs - InvalidOperationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow?view=net-5.0)). Change the code to kill the process only, if the process if still active. Also, in a non-user-interactive environment like a window service, the printing process wouldn't have a MainWindow, so `CloseMainWindow` won't close it.

```
if (fi.Length != 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
    process.StartInfo.FileName = fi.FullName;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    process.Start();

    if (!process.WaitForExit(180000))
        process.Kill();

    MoveFile(fi.FullName);
}
```

You don't print the empty files but you also don't move them. Consider moving them out of your watched folder, otherwise it could get filled up with 0 length files that would never be printed. So move the line `MoveFile(fi.FullName);` after the if-block, if this fits the requirements.

Comment: I removed the endless loop in my code and it started , I don't get the error anymore but there's another problem : the service doesn't print the files , it just move them !!! ,